# jQuery accordion opening tabs on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I have a jQuery accordion that is called from a generic accordion() function.
The issue i'm having at the minute is that the accordion is opening the tabs on page load instead of loading them in closed.

Already tried adding `$(".accordionbody").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false });` to my `$(document).ready(function($) {` and also inside the `accordion()` function.

Below is the accordion function

```
function accordion() {

 $('.accordionbody').hide(); 

 $('.accordion').find('.accordionheader').click(function(){ 

   $('.accordiontoggle').css("transform", "rotate(0deg)"); 

   var toggle_state = $(this).next().is(':visible') 

   $(this).next().slideToggle(); 

   !toggle_state ? $(this).find('.accordiontoggle').css("transform", "rotate(90deg)") : $(this).find('.accordiontoggle').css("transform", "rotate(0deg)"); 

   $(".accordionbody").not($(this).next()).slideUp();

 });

}
```

I then just have a generic call to this function in another js file.

```
accordion();
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing your html markup?

Comment: you need your accordion closed on page load ?